# external accessory api getting error, how to work with external accessory

Tags: swift, external-accessory

i am trying to work with external accessory api , wrote some code but i gets big error.
can someone tell me please, where is my problem?

this is what i wrote and the error that i get

maybe that would help my last question as well

thanks

```
var acs = EAAccessory()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let accessorys = EAAccessoryManager.shared().connectedAccessories.first
    if accessorys != nil{

        acs = accessorys!
            acs.delegate = self
    }
    let session = EASession(accessory: acs, forProtocol: acs.protocolStrings.description)
    if session != nil {
        session?.outputStream?.delegate = self
        session?.outputStream?.schedule(in: RunLoop.main, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
        session?.outputStream?.open()
        session?.inputStream?.delegate = self
        session?.inputStream?.schedule(in: RunLoop.main, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
        session?.inputStream?.open()
    }
}
```

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'EAAccessoryInitException', reason: '-init not supported. EAAccessoryManager is responsible for creating all objects.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1d963b3d 0x1cbeb067 0x1d963a85 0x29bcdf85 0xdfa24 0xdd2b8 0xdee68 0xdf03c 0x230663bb 0x231a06ef 0x231a03a5 0x230660d3 0x231a06ef 0x231a0647 0x231a03a5 0x23065633 0x232f5b1f 0x22e0ce41 0x22c052a1 0x22e0bb11 0x22e1e7c5 0x22e0935b 0x1f244c13 0x1f244acd 0x1f244db7 0x1d91ffdd 0x1d91fb05 0x1d91df51 0x1d8711af 0x1d870fd1 0x22bfee2d 0x22bf9a53 0xe0b18 0x1d05e4eb)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is not valid:

```
var acs = EAAccessory()
```

You can't create an "empty" EAAccessory.

Given how you're doing this, you probably meant:

```
var acs: EAAccessory!
```

or

```
var acs: EAAccessory?
```

That said, I would generally recommend moving your accessory handling out of view controllers and into the model layer. View controllers generally should just focus on coordinating views. They're not for driving interactions with hardware.

Comment: thank you sir, it works ,but i can't find any accessory, i like to connect mac as accessory ,is that possible ?

Comment: Macs are not an accessory. I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. EAAccessory is generally for dealing with custom MFi (Made For iPhone) devices.

Comment: thank you for your responses sir ,i am trying to make core midi app that can connect to mac , as midi controller ,i made the app with network , wifi connection but i have latency ,according to apple 20ms latency is normal but i need less than that ,so i want to try it with cable

Comment: according to apple documentation :  ( The Core MIDI framework provides APIs for communicating with MIDI (Musical Instrument Digital Interface) devices, including hardware keyboards and synthesizers. Connect from an iOS device using the dock connector or a network. For more information about using the dock connector, see Apple’s MFi program). so that means with cable i have to work with MFI program, and i believe the accessory frame work is behind the MFI programming ,is that true? do you know how its possible ?

Comment: MFi is a program for hardware manufacturers. The point of EAAccessory is to allow an app I write to communicate with a piece of hardware I build that includes an MFi chip. That doesn't apply to Mac/iPhone communication. I'm not aware of any supported low-latency protocols (particularly over USB), but you may want to look at https://rsms.me/peertalk/

Comment: thank you, do you know if i can use those code in my projects, is that open source license ? because i don't understand the GitHub ,i want to be able to sell my app .

Comment: The license is described here: https://github.com/rsms/peertalk/blob/master/LICENSE.txt